# Genymotion became laggy

Tags: android, android-emulator, virtualbox, genymotion

My Genymotion devices became very laggy, I don't know when this began to happen exactly (maybe after switching to Yosemite).

I tried everything, reinstall Genymotion, latest VirtualBox version, new device images, older Android versions, lower screen resolution, les RAM/CPU, more RAM/CPU, disconnect external screen. I ran open GL benchmarks that seemed OK.

The only weird thing I noticed is a high CPU usage from the VBoxHeadless process when idle (50% ~ 100%). I checked system monitor, Logcat, VirtualBox logs and everything else I could think of.

I am running on an iMac with OS X 10.10.1 on an SSD, 2.5Ghz Core i5, 8GB of RAM and an AMD Radeon 6750M 512 Mo. Genymotion 2.3.1, VirtualBox 4.3.20, the latest 'Custom Phone 5.0.0 Lollipop' image.

The other weird thing is that once in a while (I launched a device a lot of times and this happened only once), the device will run very smoothly (as it was running before).

Any clues on what might be the origin of this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing the device's CPU number to 1?

- On the devices list, click on the settings button on the right
- Then set the CPU number to 1 for each device you want to use

This workaround should work.
If not, I advise you to push the problem to [the support team](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/support#contact) including your host's configuration, genymotion version, ...

Comment: Already tried that :/ Thanks anyway Ezal. I'll contact the support team as you suggested.